# Cancel navigation in Reach router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reach-router

I have a component which requires confirmation before navigating to another component. There is a `Prompt` component in react router which enables to ask confirmation before navigating to another component but I can't find any similar solution in `reach-router`. Is there any way I can ask the user for confirmation before they navigate to another route and cancel the navigation if the user responds no?

Comment: https://vijayt.com/post/cancel-navigation-different-page-react-app/